# Incorporating Paypal payment into registration in express

Tags: node.js, paypal, express

I have a sign-up process that needs to incorporate a one off subscription fee which I am trying to execute using the node Paypal SDK, although question is framework agnostic I guess. At the moment I execute something like the following:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // handle errors --> show validation errors on sign-up form...
        }
        // User is valid, user persisted, show welcome page whatever...
        res.redirect('/welcome');
    });
};
```

Now I need to add the payment which should execute between the validation, which occurs in the user model (assume no JS client-side), and persisting the User to the database. However I don't see how this is possible.
So should the data be persisted regardless of whether payment is successful and then if the payment objects `cancel_url` route is executed it has to remove the user?

Also am I correct in assuming the the transaction is not performed until the user is back on your site (via the payment objects `return_url`) and the `paypal.payment.execute` method executed? In which case if the user closes the browser between entering their details on Paypal (they might assume the transaction is completed at this point) and returning to my webapp I will have a purportedly valid user in the database but never have received payment.

Sorry if this is confusing, I am trying to articulate this as best I can. Essentially what is the correct control flow for persisting a new user whilst requiring a successful payment via Paypal?